# Como llamar datos de tabla pivote

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una tabla **partners** y otra **users**, las cuales se relacionan en una tabla pivote **partner_user**, cuando quiero realizar una eliminación de un *Partner* quiero que también se elimine el *User* asignado, pero solo puedo obtener con el request el id del *Partner* y me gustaría con ese id poder buscar en la tabla pivote el id correspondiente al *User*. Espero ser claro y me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es eliminar la relación que hay en la tabla pivote, en realidad con un detach podrias eliminar dicha relación

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $partner=Partner::findOrFail($id);
    $partner->users()->detach();
    $partner->delete();
}
```

Pero en el modelo Partner tendrías que tener la siguiente función

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'partner_user')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Espero te funcione

Comment: si me sirvio aunque en realidad lo que necesitaba era esto: `$id_user = DB::select('select * from partner_user where partner_id = :id', ['id' => $partner->id]);` para acceder al id y despues borro con la función que me pasaste